# ASP.NET Core WEB API - Receive multiple files in post request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iformfile

This is my controller action:

```
// POST: api/Customers/Create
[HttpPost(), Route("Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync([FromForm] CustomerModel model)
```

And it receives a `CustomerModel`:

```
public Guid? Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
public  List<CustomerLicenseModel> LicenseFiles { get; set; }
```

My `CustomerModel` has a custom class that is a list of files of type `CustomerLicenseModel`

```
public  List<CustomerLicenseModel> LicenseFiles { get; set; }
```

And this is the `CustomerLicenseModel`:

```
public class CustomerLicenseModel
{
    public LicenseFileType LicenseFileType { get; set; }
    public IFormFile LicenseFile { get; set; }
}
```

`LicenseFileType` can be Front or Back.

```
public enum LicenseFileType
{
    Front,
    Back
}
```

How can I send this via a http request?

If I have a `List<IFormFile>` inside my `CustomerModel`, I can send multiple files via postman or swagger for an example, but I need to know what the `LicenseFileType` is.

Can somebody help?

Comment: What do you mean `I need to know what the LicenseFileType is`? You don't know what's the `enum` type or  how to pass the value?

Comment: I really don't know how to pass the values. But @XinranShen is answer below has the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Swagger`  does not support the transmission of this format by default, So I suggest you use postman to send requset.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't kwow that the solution is pass files in array.